# String index out of range: 2.Doing calculation in Postfix expression style.

Tags: java, regex, string, indexing, calculator

I'm making a RPN calculator, I have done the part of converting infix to postfix, now I want to evaluate the expression in postfix.

example:
converting from ((3 + 5  1)=8)  14 to  3 5 1  +8 = 14 (I have done that). now evaluating the latter expression.
The instructions I have:

Given a postx expression v 1:::v n,
where v i is either an operand or an operator,
the following algorithm evaluates the expression. A helper string, temp2, is
used during the calculation.

- i = 1
- while i<= n
- if v_i is an operand: Push v_i to tmp2.
- if v_i is
     an operator: Apply v_i to the top two elements of tmp2. Replace
     these by the result in tmp2.
- i = i + 1
- Output result from tmp2.

My code:

```
static int eval(String postfix) {
    int result = 0;
    String temp2 = "";
    int num1, num2;
    char operator;

    for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++) {
        char M = postfix.charAt(i);

        // if v_i is an operand: Push v_i to tmp2.
        if (Character.isDigit(postfix.charAt(i))) {
            temp2 = M + temp2;
        }

        /*
         * if v_i is an operator: Apply v_i to the top two elements of tmp2.
         * Replace these by the result in tmp2.
         */
        if (postfix.charAt(i) == '+' || postfix.charAt(i) == '-' || postfix.charAt(i) == '*'
                || postfix.charAt(i) == '/') {

            temp2 = M + temp2.substring(2);

            num1 = Character.getNumericValue(temp2.charAt(temp2.length() - 1));

            operator = postfix.charAt(i);

            num2 = Character.getNumericValue(temp2.charAt(temp2.length() + i - 1));

            switch (operator) {

            case '+':
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;

            }
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
```

at:

```
num2 = Character.getNumericValue(temp2.charAt(temp2.length() + i - 1));
```

Comment: `temp2.length() + i - 1` is a valid index only for `i <= 0`  && `i > - (temp2.length() - 1)`

Comment: Any suggestion for the problem overall?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String index out of range when accessing chars in a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668142/string-index-out-of-range-when-accessing-chars-in-a-string)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.

Comment: @RealSkeptic. I was asked to ask the question again, win a different way, with instructions given. If you can help, please do.

Comment: @Javabeginner It's good to include extra information, but you should *edit* the *original* question, not post it again.

Comment: @mastov  OK. can you actually help me with the code-problem? ^^

Comment: Your code is very hard to understand because of the use of Strings, Indices, and temporary variables. My advice (I've done it myself): Instead of storing the postfix expression as a String, store it as a `List`, where every element is either a number or an operator (or a function). Your evaluation function will look a lot nicer and will be a lot more extendable.